# Returning multiple classes in c#

Tags: c#, class, loops, return

I've got a function that returns a new class depending on the input string.

```
private classX GetData(string id)
{
   if (id == "-string1")
       return new class1(this, @"path");
   if (id == "-string2")
       return new class2(this, @"path");
   if (id == "-string3")
       return new class3(this, @"path");

   // ...

   return null;
}
```

The problem is, I want to have one condition (for example "-all") that returns every single class one by one. I have no idea how to do this.
Is there any way to return those classes one by one? Cause I do know that it won't work with 'return' as it ends the code so the rest is unreachable.

Comment: Do those classes have anything in common? Do they implement the same interface? Are they inheriting from the same base class? If not, you'll have to return them as `object` in some kind of container (like a `List<object>` or  `object[]`).

Comment: it is possible if all of your classes inherits from ClassX. You can also modify the return type to one ClassX object or a list of ClassX object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly you should, if possible, make all your classes implement a common interface, or inherit from a common abstract base class.

For example:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    // ...
}

public class ClassX : IMyInterface
{
    // ...
}

public class ClassY : IMyInterface
{
    // ...
}

public class ClassZ : IMyInterface
{
    // ...
}
```

Or:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    // ...
}

public class ClassX : MyBaseClass
{
    // ...
}

public class ClassY : MyBaseClass
{
    // ...
}

public class ClassZ : MyBaseClass
{
    // ...
}
```

Then you can implement your `GetData()` method as an `IEnumerable<IMyInterface>` (or `IEnumerable<MyBaseClass>` if using an abstract base class rather than an interface).

For example:

```
public static IEnumerable<IMyInterface> GetData(string id)
{
    if (id == "-string1" || id == "-all")
        yield return new ClassX();

    if (id == "-string2" || id == "-all")
        yield return new ClassY();

    if (id == "-string3" || id == "-all")
        yield return new ClassX();
}
```

Which you would use in a `foreach`:

```
foreach (var item in GetData("-all"))
{
    // ...
}
```

If you do not want to, or cannot, use a common base class or interface, then you will have to return objects instead, by declaring `GetData()` as:

```
 public static IEnumerable<object> GetData(string id)
```

I can't see the point of you doing that though. You'd probably have to know what the returned types were and cast accordingly before you could use them, which makes using them extremely inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

Use polymorphism (or interface, depending on your implementing) like so

```
 public baseX 
 {}

 public classX : baseX 
 {}
```

And change the function return value to a list of baseX:

```
private list<baseX> GetData(string id)
{
   list<baseX> returnList = new list<baseX>();

   if (id == "-string1")
       return returnList.add( new class1(this, @"path") );
   if (id == "-string2")
       return returnList.add( new class2(this, @"path") );
   if (id == "-string3")
       return returnList.add( new class3(this, @"path") );

   // ...

   if (id == "-All")
   {
       returnList.add( new class1(this, @"path") );
       returnList.add( new class2(this, @"path") );
       returnList.add( new class3(this, @"path") );
       // .....
   }

   return returnList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it return an array of classX. There isn't really another way besides using an array or a List

Answer (score 0):

You can change the function to return an Array then loop through the array. 
in case of one class, it will be the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to return a collection of instances, instead of a singular instance. If classX is a base class of class1,2,3 just return an IEnumerable of classX instead of a single instance. You can then use yield return to return all the instances of class 1 through 3 that you desire.

That being said, this is a very strange way of generating your classes and I wouldn't advise it on the whole.